# GET IIS detail in Classic ASP

Tags: iis

I have been looking a function in Classic ASP.
So When the page is loaded, it will show the following information:
- Active application pool name: (if possible should show the active IIS application pool name for example.com)
- Private bytes in use: (should show the private bytes for the active application pool)
- Virtual bytes in use: (should show the virtual bytes for the active application pool)

Thanks, Ravi

Answer (score 1):

There is no function in classic ASP which can provide you this. However you can use WMI providers for IIS and call them from your classic ASP page.

From [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771273(v=ws.10).aspx#To%20view%20a%20list%20of%20worker%20processes) article, we know that:

> IIS 7 lists worker processes with associated application pool names,
> and provides the following information for each worker process:

- > **Application Pool Name**. The name of the application pool. In the case
  > of Web gardens, the same application pool may be listed more than once
  > in the grid to account for different worker processes running in the
  > application pool.
- > **Process ID**. The worker process identifier (ID) associated with the
  > application pool.
- > **State**. The state of the process, such as starting, running, or
  > stopping.
- > **CPU %**. The percentage of time that the worker process has used the CPU
  > since last update. This corresponds to **CPU Usage** in Task Manager.
- > **Private Bytes (KB)**. The current size of memory committed to a worker
  > process, which cannot be shared with other processes. This corresponds
  > to Virtual Memory Size in Windows Task Manager.
- > **Virtual Bytes (KB)**. The current size of the virtual address space for
  > a worker process. This does not correspond to anything in Windows Task
  > Manager.

> **NOTE**: This requires the **`RequestMonitorModule`** to be installed

You will need to use the following WMI classes:

- [WorkerProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347447(v=vs.90).aspx) class
- [ApplicationPoolContainsProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691435(v=vs.90).aspx) class

Refer this link on how to get started on calling **WMI** in an **ASP** page:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20211020113425/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/082802-1.shtml#postadlink
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389395(v=vs.85).aspx